# Tracked background does not show in final render.

Tags: rendering, video, tracking

I created a camera tracking animation: a dinosaur walking in my street. Everything worked fine until I deleted the video background and added a new one. In render view I can see the result I want: my 3d dinosaur, the shadow catcher and the video at the background. When I render it, the video does not show. The background is a gray color. 
I don't understand why it doesn't works, because the first video background did render in the final result.

Help!

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project  Add images (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your render layers, or compositing nodes or render settings.

Comment: Okay, can I also give the file and the video I want to be in the background?

Comment: @JesseAlberts You can upload a .blend here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, but there is no need for the video.

Comment: Did you update the composite node to use the new video?

Comment: No I don't. But I didn't used nodes for the first video either. Anyway, where can I find those nodes?

Comment: I didn't create any nodes about backgrounds btw, but there may be a node I don't know

Answer (score -2):

Thank you! I found the nodes I needed to change just under one button: screen layout 'compositing' > Node tree display and edit 'compositing nodes'. The wrong display was set so I couldn't see the nodes for background.